# publish asp.net project on apache server

Tags: c#, .net, apache, mono

I am new to .NET and I have downloaded a project from github that I want to run on localhost apache server. I found a lot of information on the internet on how to use .NET for apache Server (mono etc.) and everything seems to be installed correctly and I am rather unable to find an answer to the basic question on how to access the project's web UI from the browser. I am used to php and html and therefore was looking for an index-file which I cannot find in the project folder structure. What am I missing?

Thank you so much for all your help.
Steffen

Comment: Is your ASP.NET website using WebForms or MVC architecture? Also, when you try to access it, does it display a 404 error message or something else?

Comment: I copied the project folders into /var/www but if I call the folder http://localhost/projectxxx then I get 403

Comment: Or, to put it differently: there is no index.aspx file in the project root - is that possible?

Comment: That is the project: https://github.com/drinks-wallet/drinks-server. Thanks for ANY hint!!!

Comment: By the looks of https://github.com/drinks-wallet/drinks-server/tree/master/Drinks.Web/Views/Home it would appear that you need to go to http://{domain}/Home/Index

Comment: ^ That looks like the login portal

Answer (score 0):

After browsing your project structure, I believe that [this](https://github.com/drinks-wallet/drinks-server/blob/master/Drinks.Web/Views/Home/Index.cshtml) is the login portal.

For this reason, try to go to:

http://your_domain/Home/Index

Furthermore, in your [App_Start/RouteConfig.cs](https://github.com/drinks-wallet/drinks-server/blob/master/Drinks.Web/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs) class, it says:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note: `controller = "Home", action = "Index"`

Comment: puhh, doesn't work (http://localhost/Home/Index). I am so desperate to get this running. do you have any other idea?

Comment: Did you publish the Drinks.Web project to the `var/www` folder?

Comment: That is exactly the problem - I do not know how to publish it on my apache2 localhost. There seem to be different ways but all are different depending on which type of .net 'project' it is but I do not know enough about .net in order to tell what kind of treatment the project needs in order to deploy it in apache...